# How can I stop PHP from changing all my decimal separators?

Tags: php, mysql

My (MySQL) tables have columns with currency values set as Decimal(10,2) with decimals separated by commas. However whenever i query them, php turns all my commas into periods and invalidates my results. Can I stop it doing that? It affects both my SELECT and my INSERT/UPDATE.

When I select, for example, 123,00 php turns it into 12300.00; same for inserting a number: i insert 123,00 but the value in the table becomes 12300,00 again. Is there a way to make comma the default decimal separator?

Comment: You need to do your formatting in your app, and leave the database side alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you looked in to
http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

```
$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
```

Comment: that's what I thought but does that change the way in which it gets the results from the mysql queries? I can't really try right now because I can't get the server admin on the phone to install the locale I need

Comment: see if `sprintf('%.2f', '123,00');` helps for insert/update and for displaying it do a replace on the decimal to comma

Comment: yeah once i got home i realized just how easy it is. multiply by 100, replace . with ,. Guess I got to tired to think straight.

Comment: Just a funny heads up about the issue. It seems to have fixed itself over night. Now php interprets everything and passes everything correctly. I have no idea how it happened but I'm not complaining.

Comment: @Bogdan that good its working now, but it wouldn't hurt to see if you or the admin can check logs ect to see what may of caused it so, the issue dosn't arise again.

Comment: It was just my co-worker in another city changing the locale settings without telling anyone.

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP part this might me helpful

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

This should give you a clue on how to get the right output from your PHP code.
Don't care on how the database stores your numbers, neither on how PHP does it internally.
Use the number_format to get your desired output.

See also [PHP: number-format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for more on that.

Comment: yes, i've originally thought of that but the problem is that when the result of the query is 123,45 php immediately interprets it as 12345.00 I can't get around it and the only workaround i found was changing the column type to char/varchar but that also doesn't work cuz I need to order them and such.